# Retrieving the DNS response

Tags: shell, powershell

As part of the development of a Shell or Powershell script, I need an instruction allowing me to retrieve in a variable, the IP address of a given site.
Whether in shell or powershell, please help me

Comment: `test-netconnection`. Look into that and you'll get on the right direction. SO is not a cdoewriting service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In powershell you can use

```
[System.Net.DNS]::GetHostAddresses("www.mydns.org")[0].IpAddressToString
```

`GetHostAddresses` may return multiple IP addresses. `[0]` returns the first one. `IpAddressToString` get the common representation of the address (for instance 63.251.171.81)